# Could the Fleximobile iPhone spyware be installed on a victim's iPhone just by having them connect it to a hacked computer via USB?

Tags: iphone, spyware

My computer recently got hacked and I want to know how likely it is that my non-jailbroken iPhone got hacked as well when I was charging it with my laptop.

Btw, what other ways are there to see if Fleximobile is installed on my iPhone and what other ways can Fleximobile be installed? Could it be installed without a prompt from the system?

Fleximobile site: https://www.fleximobile.com/en/shop/spy-software/spy-software-iphone-without-jailbreak/

Comment: Why specifically do you think that Fleximobile was installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where you got that page, but I read the whole page including their FAQ:

> How can I tell if FLEXImobile is installed on my phone?
>
> FLEXImobile is not a virus and must be deliberately installed onto the Target phone directly, with a unique set of steps and configurations. It will not perform any functions that were not configured by human intervention. However, it does not install any visible program menus, folders or icons. Once installed, it may only be accessed or uninstalled by equally deliberate human intervention.

That means, if we can rely on them (which I think so), that it can not be installed through the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question has been asked some days ago. But I would like to answer it.

I am officially from FLEXImobile.

There is no way for us to have our products installed on other devices remotely. To have our Apps installed, one needs physical access to the device.

Hope this answer is clarifying.

Cheers!